# Python script with MQTT not working when compiled with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, mqtt

So I have a python script that I made. Basically it connects to a mqtt broker using paho-mqtt and display data in a graph using mathplotlib. It works perfectly fine on my computer, but I need to share the script with some people, and since I'm not sure how tech savy they are, to save them the trouble of installing python, pip, and all the dependecies needed, I looked into turning my script to an exe file. I found pyinstaller, and tried it.
But the exe it gives me doesn't work.
It won't connect to the MQTT broker, and I'm getting this error :

```
  File "app.py", line 123, in <module>
  File "paho\mqtt\client.py", line 914, in connect
  File "paho\mqtt\client.py", line 1044, in reconnect
  File "paho\mqtt\client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
  File "socket.py", line 845, in create_connection
  File "socket.py", line 833, in create_connection
TimeoutError: timed out
[16016] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

The line it refers to is the client.connect(...)
Also, the execution is really slow, it takes something like 30 secondes for the first prompt to appear in the cli, where as before compilation it's almost instant.
The command I used to build : `pyinstaller --onefile 'app.py'`

Here is a simplified version of the code that still generate the issue :

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from datetime import datetime

isReading = True

timestamps = []
dataX = []

finish = False

newData = False
lasttime = None
lastX = None
#for testing : 
sensorid = "sensorid"

#MQTT functions--------------------
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    client.subscribe("data/" + sensorid)
    
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    if isReading == True:
        global newData, lasttime, lastX, lastY, lastZ
        newData = True
        data_string = msg.payload.decode('utf8')
        data_json = json.loads(data_string)
        lasttime = data_json.get('time')
        lastX = data_json.get('X')

#/MQTT functions--------------------

#PLT funtions-------------------
def on_plt_close(event):
    global finish
    finish = True
    client.loop_stop()

def animate(i):
    global newData, lasttime, lastX, lastY, lastZ
    if newData == True:
        timestamps.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(lasttime)))
        dataX.append(int(lastX))
        newData = False
    ax1.cla()
    ax1.plot_date(timestamps, dataX, 'r', label="X", xdate=True, ydate=False)

    ax1.legend()

#/PLT functions---------------------

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', on_plt_close)
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, 500)
#setup and connect MQTT client
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("ip", 1883, 60)
client.loop_start()
plt.show()

while finish == False:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Does anyone know what I do wrong ?

Comment: What is the "first prompt to appear in the cli" (i.e. is it output after the MQTT connection is up) and are you running the executable on the same machine as you tested on before using `pyinstaller`?. Currently it appears that the issue is a timeout connecting to the MQTT broker. Are you able to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (the code is relevant because it enables us to try to replicate the issue - also please confirm python and pyinstaller versions).

Comment: My python is in v3.10.2 and pyinstaller is in v4.10. What I call the first prompt in the CLI is the first text to appear after the terminal opens when I execute the .exe . In my real code, it's an line with "sensor = input("choose a sensor")" basically, and it happens before the client try to connect to the broker. I shaved down the code to something that still works, and editing it into the post

Comment: And yes, it's the same machine

Comment: I have used `pyinstaller` to build the code you posted (with `"ip"` edited to `"127.0.0.1"` ) and this worked fine (it connected to my local Mosquitto instance and the blank graph came up). This was in a fresh venv with the same versions of python/pyinstaller (on Windows 11).